# JButton update label

Tags: java, eclipse, label, jbutton

As in my last question, I declare that I'm very new to coding and Java is my only current language.

I'm building my first entirely independent project in eclipse, using a lot of Java imports.

It is a POS till system, it has 24 menu item buttons which are labelled by taking a string that holds null value to begin with.

I have an admin panel and from this panel I can update the title and price associated with the menu item button.

When I click "set" button relating to that particular menu item button, the string and double for item name and price update properly but title printed on JButton does not change.

What am I doing wrong/missing please?

Code follows:

```
public class Background implements ActionListener {

double menitprice1 = 0.0;
double menitprice2 = 0.0;
double menitprice3 = 0.0;
double menitprice4 = 0.0;
double menitprice5 = 0.0;
double menitprice6 = 0.0;
double menitprice7 = 0.0;
double menitprice8 = 0.0;
double menitprice9 = 0.0;
double menitprice10 = 0.0;
double menitprice11 = 0.0;
double menitprice12 = 0.0;
double menitprice13 = 0.0;
double menitprice14 = 0.0;
double menitprice15 = 0.0;
double menitprice16 = 0.0;
double menitprice17 = 0.0;
double menitprice18 = 0.0;
double menitprice19 = 0.0;
double menitprice20 = 0.0;
double menitprice21 = 0.0;
double menitprice22 = 0.0;
double menitprice23 = 0.0;
double menitprice24 = 0.0;

String menit1;
String menit2;
String menit3;
String menit4;
String menit5;
String menit6;
String menit7;
String menit8;
String menit9;
String menit10;
String menit11;
String menit12;
String menit13;
String menit14;
String menit15;
String menit16;
String menit17;
String menit18;
String menit19;
String menit20;
String menit21;
String menit22;
String menit23;
String menit24;
String adminPassword = "Password";

int splitParty;

JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
JFrame adminFrame = new JFrame();
JFrame payFrame = new JFrame();
JFrame splitFrame = new JFrame();
JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame();

Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
Panel adminPanel = new Panel();
Panel payPanel = new Panel();
Panel splitPanel = new Panel();
Panel loginPanel = new Panel();


JTextArea summaryList = new JTextArea();
JTextArea summaryListTotal = new JTextArea();
JTextArea dueAmount = new JTextArea();
JTextArea splitAmount = new JTextArea("How many people?");
JTextArea totalSplits = new JTextArea();
JTextArea splitInput = new JTextArea();
JTextArea logInPassword = new JTextArea();
JTextArea itemsList = new JTextArea("Menu item:");
JTextArea list1 = new JTextArea("Item 1");
JTextArea list2 = new JTextArea("Item 2");
JTextArea list3 = new JTextArea("Item 3");
JTextArea list4 = new JTextArea("Item 4");
JTextArea list5 = new JTextArea("Item 5");
JTextArea list6 = new JTextArea("Item 6");
JTextArea list7 = new JTextArea("Item 7");
JTextArea list8 = new JTextArea("Item 8");
JTextArea list9 = new JTextArea("Item 9");
JTextArea list10 = new JTextArea("Item 10");
JTextArea list11 = new JTextArea("Item 11");
JTextArea list12 = new JTextArea("Item 12");
JTextArea list13 = new JTextArea("Item 13");
JTextArea list14 = new JTextArea("Item 14");
JTextArea list15 = new JTextArea("Item 15");
JTextArea list16 = new JTextArea("Item 16");
JTextArea list17 = new JTextArea("Item 17");
JTextArea list18 = new JTextArea("Item 18");
JTextArea list19 = new JTextArea("Item 19");
JTextArea list20 = new JTextArea("Item 20");
JTextArea list21 = new JTextArea("Item 21");
JTextArea list22 = new JTextArea("Item 22");
JTextArea list23 = new JTextArea("Item 23");
JTextArea list24 = new JTextArea("Item 24");
JTextArea itemIs = new JTextArea("Item Name");
JTextArea price = new JTextArea("Price");
JTextArea setItem1 = new JTextArea(menit1);
JTextArea setItem2 = new JTextArea(menit2);
JTextArea setItem3 = new JTextArea(menit3);
JTextArea setItem4 = new JTextArea(menit4);
JTextArea setItem5 = new JTextArea(menit5);
JTextArea setItem6 = new JTextArea(menit6);
JTextArea setItem7 = new JTextArea(menit7);
JTextArea setItem8 = new JTextArea(menit8);
JTextArea setItem9 = new JTextArea(menit9);
JTextArea setItem10 = new JTextArea(menit10);
JTextArea setItem11 = new JTextArea(menit11);
JTextArea setItem12 = new JTextArea(menit12);
JTextArea setItem13 = new JTextArea(menit13);
JTextArea setItem14 = new JTextArea(menit14);
JTextArea setItem15 = new JTextArea(menit15);
JTextArea setItem16 = new JTextArea(menit16);
JTextArea setItem17 = new JTextArea(menit17);
JTextArea setItem18 = new JTextArea(menit18);
JTextArea setItem19 = new JTextArea(menit19);
JTextArea setItem20 = new JTextArea(menit20);
JTextArea setItem21 = new JTextArea(menit21);
JTextArea setItem22 = new JTextArea(menit22);
JTextArea setItem23 = new JTextArea(menit23);
JTextArea setItem24 = new JTextArea(menit24);
JTextArea setPrice1 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice1));
JTextArea setPrice2 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice2));
JTextArea setPrice3 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice3));
JTextArea setPrice4 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice4));
JTextArea setPrice5 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice5));
JTextArea setPrice6 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice6));
JTextArea setPrice7 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice7));
JTextArea setPrice8 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice8));
JTextArea setPrice9 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice9));
JTextArea setPrice10 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice10));
JTextArea setPrice11 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice11));
JTextArea setPrice12 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice12));
JTextArea setPrice13 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice13));
JTextArea setPrice14 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice14));
JTextArea setPrice15 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice15));
JTextArea setPrice16 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice16));
JTextArea setPrice17 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice17));
JTextArea setPrice18 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice18));
JTextArea setPrice19 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice19));
JTextArea setPrice20 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice20));
JTextArea setPrice21 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice21));
JTextArea setPrice22 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice22));
JTextArea setPrice23 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice23));
JTextArea setPrice24 = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(menitprice24));

JButton menuItem1 = new JButton(menit1 + " " + menitprice1);
JButton menuItem2 = new JButton(menit2 + " " + menitprice2);
JButton menuItem3 = new JButton(menit3 + " " + menitprice3);
JButton menuItem4 = new JButton(menit4 + " " + menitprice4);
JButton menuItem5 = new JButton(menit5 + " " + menitprice5);
JButton menuItem6 = new JButton(menit6 + " " + menitprice6);
JButton menuItem7 = new JButton(menit7 + " " + menitprice7);
JButton menuItem8 = new JButton(menit8 + " " + menitprice8);
JButton menuItem9 = new JButton(menit9 + " " + menitprice9);
JButton menuItem10 = new JButton(menit10 + " " + menitprice10);
JButton menuItem11 = new JButton(menit11 + " " + menitprice11);
JButton menuItem12 = new JButton(menit12 + " " + menitprice12);
JButton menuItem13 = new JButton(menit13 + " " + menitprice13);
JButton menuItem14 = new JButton(menit14 + " " + menitprice14);
JButton menuItem15 = new JButton(menit15 + " " + menitprice15);
JButton menuItem16 = new JButton(menit16 + " " + menitprice16);
JButton menuItem17 = new JButton(menit17 + " " + menitprice17);
JButton menuItem18 = new JButton(menit18 + " " + menitprice18);
JButton menuItem19 = new JButton(menit19 + " " + menitprice19);
JButton menuItem20 = new JButton(menit20 + " " + menitprice20);
JButton menuItem21 = new JButton(menit21 + " " + menitprice21);
JButton menuItem22 = new JButton(menit22 + " " + menitprice22);
JButton menuItem23 = new JButton(menit23 + " " + menitprice23);
JButton menuItem24 = new JButton(menit24 + " " + menitprice24);
JButton adminButton = new JButton("Admin Control");
JButton payButton = new JButton("Payment");
JButton cashOpt = new JButton("Cash");
JButton cardOpt = new JButton("Card");
JButton splitOpt = new JButton("Split Payment");
JButton splitCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
JButton splitSubmit = new JButton("Split it");
JButton passwordSubmit = new JButton("Log in");
JButton menItSet1 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet2 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet3 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet4 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet5 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet6 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet7 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet8 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet9 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet10 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet11 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet12 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet13 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet14 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet15 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet16 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet17 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet18 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet19 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet20 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet21 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet22 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet23 = new JButton("set");
JButton menItSet24 = new JButton("set");

public Background() {

    Border listBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 3);
    Font listFont = new Font("ariel", Font.BOLD, 27);

    // Admin Log in
    loginFrame.setVisible(false);
    loginFrame.setTitle("Indy POS: Admin log in");
    loginFrame.setSize(400, 200);
    loginFrame.setResizable(false);

    loginFrame.add(loginPanel);
    loginPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    loginPanel.setLayout(null);

    loginPanel.add(logInPassword);
    logInPassword.setBounds(100, 50, 200, 50);
    logInPassword.setBorder(listBorder);
    logInPassword.setFont(listFont);
    logInPassword.setBackground(Color.white);
    logInPassword.setForeground(Color.lightGray);

    loginPanel.add(passwordSubmit);
    passwordSubmit.setBounds(125, 112, 150, 50);

    passwordSubmit.addActionListener(this);

    // Admin area
    adminFrame.setVisible(false);
    adminFrame.setTitle("Indy POS: Admin Control");
    adminFrame.setSize(850, 750);

    adminFrame.add(adminPanel);
    adminPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    adminPanel.setLayout(null);

    adminPanel.add(list1);
    list1.setEditable(false);
    list1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list1.setBorder(listBorder);
    list1.setBounds(50, 25, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list2);
    list2.setEditable(false);
    list2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list2.setBorder(listBorder);
    list2.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list3);
    list3.setEditable(false);
    list3.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list3.setBorder(listBorder);
    list3.setBounds(50, 75, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list4);
    list4.setEditable(false);
    list4.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list4.setBorder(listBorder);
    list4.setBounds(50, 100, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list5);
    list5.setEditable(false);
    list5.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list5.setBorder(listBorder);
    list5.setBounds(50, 125, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list6);
    list6.setEditable(false);
    list6.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list6.setBorder(listBorder);
    list6.setBounds(50, 150, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list7);
    list7.setEditable(false);
    list7.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list7.setBorder(listBorder);
    list7.setBounds(50, 175, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list8);
    list8.setEditable(false);
    list8.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list8.setBorder(listBorder);
    list8.setBounds(50, 200, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list9);
    list9.setEditable(false);
    list9.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list9.setBorder(listBorder);
    list9.setBounds(50, 225, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list10);
    list10.setEditable(false);
    list10.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list10.setBorder(listBorder);
    list10.setBounds(50, 250, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list11);
    list11.setEditable(false);
    list11.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list11.setBorder(listBorder);
    list11.setBounds(50, 275, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list12);
    list12.setEditable(false);
    list12.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list12.setBorder(listBorder);
    list12.setBounds(50, 300, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list13);
    list13.setEditable(false);
    list13.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list13.setBorder(listBorder);
    list13.setBounds(50, 325, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list14);
    list14.setEditable(false);
    list14.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list14.setBorder(listBorder);
    list14.setBounds(50, 350, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list15);
    list15.setEditable(false);
    list15.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list15.setBorder(listBorder);
    list15.setBounds(50, 375, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list16);
    list16.setEditable(false);
    list16.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list16.setBorder(listBorder);
    list16.setBounds(50, 400, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list17);
    list17.setEditable(false);
    list17.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list17.setBorder(listBorder);
    list17.setBounds(50, 425, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list18);
    list18.setEditable(false);
    list18.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list18.setBorder(listBorder);
    list18.setBounds(50, 450, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list19);
    list19.setEditable(false);
    list19.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list19.setBorder(listBorder);
    list19.setBounds(50, 475, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list20);
    list20.setEditable(false);
    list20.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list20.setBorder(listBorder);
    list20.setBounds(50, 500, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list21);
    list21.setEditable(false);
    list21.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list21.setBorder(listBorder);
    list21.setBounds(50, 525, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list22);
    list22.setEditable(false);
    list22.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list22.setBorder(listBorder);
    list22.setBounds(50, 550, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list23);
    list23.setEditable(false);
    list23.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list23.setBorder(listBorder);
    list23.setBounds(50, 575, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(list24);
    list24.setEditable(false);
    list24.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    list24.setBorder(listBorder);
    list24.setBounds(50, 600, 50, 25);

    adminPanel.add(itemIs);
    itemIs.setEditable(false);
    itemIs.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    itemIs.setBounds(150, 0, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(price);
    price.setEditable(false);
    price.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    price.setBounds(350, 0, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem1);
    setItem1.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem1.setBounds(150, 25, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem2);
    setItem2.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem2.setBounds(150, 50, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem3);
    setItem3.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem3.setBounds(150, 75, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem4);
    setItem4.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem4.setBounds(150, 100, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem5);
    setItem5.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem5.setBounds(150, 125, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem6);
    setItem6.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem6.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem7);
    setItem7.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem7.setBounds(150, 175, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem8);
    setItem8.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem8.setBounds(150, 200, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem9);
    setItem9.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem9.setBounds(150, 225, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem10);
    setItem10.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem10.setBounds(150, 250, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem11);
    setItem11.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem11.setBounds(150, 275, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem12);
    setItem12.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem12.setBounds(150, 300, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem13);
    setItem13.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem13.setBounds(150, 325, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem14);
    setItem14.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem14.setBounds(150, 350, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem15);
    setItem15.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem15.setBounds(150, 375, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem16);
    setItem16.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem16.setBounds(150, 400, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem17);
    setItem17.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem17.setBounds(150, 425, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem18);
    setItem18.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem18.setBounds(150, 450, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem19);
    setItem19.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem19.setBounds(150, 475, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem20);
    setItem20.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem20.setBounds(150, 500, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem21);
    setItem21.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem21.setBounds(150, 525, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem22);
    setItem22.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem22.setBounds(150, 550, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem23);
    setItem23.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem23.setBounds(150, 575, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setItem24);
    setItem24.setBorder(listBorder);
    setItem24.setBounds(150, 600, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice1);
    setPrice1.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice1.setBounds(350, 25, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice2);
    setPrice2.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice2.setBounds(350, 50, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice3);
    setPrice3.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice3.setBounds(350, 75, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice4);
    setPrice4.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice4.setBounds(350, 100, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice5);
    setPrice5.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice5.setBounds(350, 125, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice6);
    setPrice6.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice6.setBounds(350, 150, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice7);
    setPrice7.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice7.setBounds(350, 175, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice8);
    setPrice8.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice8.setBounds(350, 200, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice9);
    setPrice9.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice9.setBounds(350, 225, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice10);
    setPrice10.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice10.setBounds(350, 250, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice11);
    setPrice11.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice11.setBounds(350, 275, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice12);
    setPrice12.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice12.setBounds(350, 300, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice13);
    setPrice13.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice13.setBounds(350, 325, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice14);
    setPrice14.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice14.setBounds(350, 350, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice15);
    setPrice15.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice15.setBounds(350, 375, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice16);
    setPrice16.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice16.setBounds(350, 400, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice17);
    setPrice17.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice17.setBounds(350, 425, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice18);
    setPrice18.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice18.setBounds(350, 450, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice19);
    setPrice19.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice19.setBounds(350, 475, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice20);
    setPrice20.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice20.setBounds(350, 500, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice21);
    setPrice21.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice21.setBounds(350, 525, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice22);
    setPrice22.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice22.setBounds(350, 550, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice23);
    setPrice23.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice23.setBounds(350, 575, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(setPrice24);
    setPrice24.setBorder(listBorder);
    setPrice24.setBounds(350, 600, 150, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet1);
    menItSet1.setBounds(550, 25, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet2);
    menItSet2.setBounds(550, 50, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet3);
    menItSet3.setBounds(550, 75, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet4);
    menItSet4.setBounds(550, 100, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet5);
    menItSet5.setBounds(550, 125, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet6);
    menItSet6.setBounds(550, 150, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet7);
    menItSet7.setBounds(550, 175, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet8);
    menItSet8.setBounds(550, 200, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet9);
    menItSet9.setBounds(550, 225, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet10);
    menItSet10.setBounds(550, 250, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet11);
    menItSet11.setBounds(550, 275, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet12);
    menItSet12.setBounds(550, 300, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet13);
    menItSet13.setBounds(550, 325, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet14);
    menItSet14.setBounds(550, 350, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet15);
    menItSet15.setBounds(550, 375, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet16);
    menItSet16.setBounds(550, 400, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet17);
    menItSet17.setBounds(550, 425, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet18);
    menItSet18.setBounds(550, 450, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet19);
    menItSet19.setBounds(550, 475, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet20);
    menItSet20.setBounds(550, 500, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet21);
    menItSet21.setBounds(550, 525, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet22);
    menItSet22.setBounds(550, 550, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet23);
    menItSet23.setBounds(550, 575, 100, 25);

    adminPanel.add(menItSet24);
    menItSet24.setBounds(550, 600, 100, 25);

    menItSet1.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet2.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet3.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet4.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet5.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet6.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet7.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet8.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet9.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet10.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet11.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet12.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet13.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet14.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet15.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet16.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet17.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet18.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet19.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet20.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet21.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet22.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet23.addActionListener(this);
    menItSet24.addActionListener(this);

    //Payment area
    payFrame.setVisible(false);
    payFrame.setTitle("Indy POS: Payment");
    payFrame.setSize(600, 300);
    payFrame.setResizable(false);

    payFrame.add(payPanel);
    payPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    payPanel.setLayout(null);

    payPanel.add(dueAmount);
    dueAmount.setBounds(100, 50, 250, 100);
    dueAmount.setBorder(listBorder);
    dueAmount.setFont(listFont);
    dueAmount.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    dueAmount.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    dueAmount.setEditable(false);

    payPanel.add(totalSplits);
    totalSplits.setBounds(400, 50, 150, 100);
    totalSplits.setBorder(listBorder);
    totalSplits.setFont(listFont);
    totalSplits.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    totalSplits.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    totalSplits.setEditable(false);

    payPanel.add(cashOpt);
    cashOpt.setBounds(100, 200, 100, 50);
    payPanel.add(cardOpt);
    cardOpt.setBounds(250, 200, 100, 50);
    payPanel.add(splitOpt);
    splitOpt.setBounds(400, 200, 150, 50);

    cashOpt.addActionListener(this);
    cardOpt.addActionListener(this);
    splitOpt.addActionListener(this);

    // Split area
    splitFrame.setVisible(false);
    splitFrame.setTitle("Indy POS: Split Order");
    splitFrame.setSize(450, 200);
    splitFrame.setResizable(false);

    splitFrame.add(splitPanel);
    splitPanel.setLayout(null);
    splitPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    splitPanel.add(splitAmount);
    splitAmount.setBounds(20, 25, 260, 47);
    splitAmount.setEditable(false);
    splitAmount.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    splitAmount.setFont(listFont);
    splitAmount.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    splitPanel.add(splitInput);
    splitInput.setBorder(listBorder);
    splitInput.setFont(listFont);
    splitInput.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    splitInput.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    splitInput.setBounds(100, 75, 100, 50);

    splitPanel.add(splitSubmit);
    splitSubmit.setBounds(250, 75, 100, 50);

    splitPanel.add(splitCancel);
    splitCancel.setBounds(100, 175, 100, 50);

    // Cash area

    // Card area

    // Main area
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setTitle("Indy POS");
    mainFrame.setSize(1000, 750);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    mainPanel.setLayout(null);

    mainPanel.add(summaryList);
    summaryList.setBounds(100, 50, 300, 575);
    summaryList.setBorder(listBorder);
    summaryList.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    summaryList.setEditable(false);
    summaryList.setFont(listFont);
    summaryList.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    mainPanel.add(summaryListTotal);
    summaryListTotal.setBounds(100, 650, 150, 50);
    summaryListTotal.setBorder(listBorder);
    summaryListTotal.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    summaryListTotal.setEditable(false);
    summaryListTotal.setFont(listFont);
    summaryListTotal.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    mainPanel.add(payButton);
    payButton.setBounds(300, 650, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem1);
    menuItem1.setBounds(500, 50, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem2);
    menuItem2.setBounds(650, 50, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem3);
    menuItem3.setBounds(800, 50, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem4);
    menuItem4.setBounds(500, 125, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem5);
    menuItem5.setBounds(650, 125, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem6);
    menuItem6.setBounds(800, 125, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem7);
    menuItem7.setBounds(500, 200, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem8);
    menuItem8.setBounds(650, 200, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem9);
    menuItem9.setBounds(800, 200, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem10);
    menuItem10.setBounds(500, 275, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem11);
    menuItem11.setBounds(650, 275, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem12);
    menuItem12.setBounds(800, 275, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem13);
    menuItem13.setBounds(500, 350, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem14);
    menuItem14.setBounds(650, 350, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem15);
    menuItem15.setBounds(800, 350, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem16);
    menuItem16.setBounds(500, 425, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem17);
    menuItem17.setBounds(650, 425, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem18);
    menuItem18.setBounds(800, 425, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem19);
    menuItem19.setBounds(500, 500, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem20);
    menuItem20.setBounds(650, 500, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem21);
    menuItem21.setBounds(800, 500, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem22);
    menuItem22.setBounds(500, 575, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem23);
    menuItem23.setBounds(650, 575, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(menuItem24);
    menuItem24.setBounds(800, 575, 100, 50);
    mainPanel.add(adminButton);
    adminButton.setBounds(750, 650, 150, 50);

    menuItem1.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem2.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem3.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem4.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem5.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem6.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem7.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem8.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem9.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem10.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem11.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem12.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem13.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem14.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem15.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem16.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem17.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem18.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem19.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem20.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem21.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem22.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem23.addActionListener(this);
    menuItem24.addActionListener(this);
    adminButton.addActionListener(this);
    payButton.addActionListener(this);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
Object source = e.getSource();

if (source == payButton){
    payFrame.setVisible(true);
}
if (source == splitOpt){
    splitFrame.setVisible(true);
}
if (source == adminButton){
    loginFrame.setVisible(true);
    splitFrame.setVisible(false);
    payFrame.setVisible(false);
}
if (source == passwordSubmit){
    if (logInPassword.getText().equals(adminPassword)){
        loginFrame.setVisible(false);
        adminFrame.setVisible(true);    
    }
    else logInPassword.setText(null);
        logInPassword.append("Incorrect");
}
if (source == menItSet1){
    menit1.equals(setItem1.getText());
    menitprice1 = Double.parseDouble(setPrice1.getText());

}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a String and then pass the value from that String into your action listener. Please find underneath a local String (should be an Instance, but for testing I have made a local one). And then I have passed it to the button.
[image: Print screen of the value changing]

```
if (source == menItSet1){
    String text = setItem1.getText();

    menitprice1 = Double.parseDouble(setPrice1.getText());
    menuItem1.setText(text + " " + menitprice1);
}
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much